# Is there a way I can nest two column datas under one column header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, ipywidgets

What I want to be doing looks something like:

```
index   Price

0      1000 -20
1      500   30
2      200    0
```

I want to do this because I want to keep track of the price changes? I'm using a ipywidget where I want to use the delta to change the cell color. If delta is > 0 i want the price cell where I display it to be green and < 0 to be red.

Please help!

[This is what I want my dataframe to end up looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mNoy.png)

Comment: You can have a list in a dataframe column, but I don't think that's really what you want, either... `pd.DataFrame({'Price':[[1000,0],[500,30]]})`. Why not have two columns, one for start and one for end, and then a third with the delta? I'm not familiar with ipywidget, so maybe there is some requirement there.

Comment: I think I could do the separate columns, but I don't want to show the delta or the start column. I'd just want the latest data entry and the cell color would change according to the delta. But I was trying to see if there was any more efficient and easy way of doing this.

Comment: can you post your expected output from the given sample dataframe?

Comment: @AnuragDabas I just posted a picture.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
a = np.array([2,3,4])
b = np.array([3,4,5])
data = pd.DataFrame(a)
c = np.vstack((a,b)).T
data['ab'] = list(c)
```

Comment: I don't think this does it. This will just make another column with the two columns as list.

Comment: what is use case for it ?

Comment: Trying to figure out if I pass a list or a dictionary as data, can I display it without a column header? I guess purely to test the limitations and get an idea of what I can and can't do when I have a huge dataset.